Couple become ghost after their car crash
Don't know the title but it's not Beetlejuice or Haunting of Winchester House or The Others.
It's at least 20 years old at least.
A couple in a car crash in the country. They climb out of the wreckage and make their way through the woods and come across a house. They seek shelter there. It's haunted. Fast forward.  They are the ghosts; they were actually killed in the crash.

Hi! Was the movie American? Do you remember any other scenes, characters or dialogue?

It can be Topper (1937), from Wikipedia:

George (Cary Grant) and Marion (Constance Bennett) Kerby are as rich as they are irresponsible. When George wrecks their classy sports car, they wake up from the accident as ghosts. Realizing they aren’t in heaven or hell because they’ve never been responsible enough to do good deeds or bad ones, they decide that freeing their old friend Cosmo Topper (Roland Young) from his regimented lifestyle will be their ticket into heaven.

Topper was the first black-and-white film to be digitally colorized, re-released in 1985 by Hal Roach Studios.

I was searching for this movie for years. The one I found was Voices (1973).  Is that the movie you looking for?

Can you add what parts from the movie you suggest match with the original question?
